# Search Mac App Store for Applications to open File

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, app-store

is there any way to open the Mac App Store and search for applications that can handle a given file type? Like in the Finder:

```
Right Click > Open With > App Store...
```

and `uti:public.image` will be inserted into the search field (for images).

I was able to search the App Store via `macappstore://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?q=<searchstring>` but this won't work for something link `uti:public.image`, only for *normal* searched like "iPhoto" e.g.

Sadly those specific searches only work from the search field. Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the App Store search box, enter `extension:` followed by the extension in question.

Comment: I want to perform this search via code, without typing anything into the search field